# Reset start and stop times for songs in iTunes

Tags: itunes

For some reason some of songs in my iTunes library have the start and stop time set so the entire song is not played. I tried selecting my entire library and then "Get Info", but the "Multiple Item Information" box does not allow me to change the start/stop lengths for more than one song at a time.

So how can I change these settings for my entire library (I want to remove them so I get the whole song) without having to select each song. With over 2000 songs in my library and no way of knowing which ones are 'infected' without testing each one, it simply is not practical to do it manually

Comment: Are you on Windows or OS X?  If the latter, you should be able to get an AppleScript to alter the start/finish time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a Mac, try this AppleScript: [Reset Tracks Start-Stop](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=resettracksstartstop).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with just one CD in copied into iTunes. To resolve it:

For each song I had to *uncheck* the "remember playback position" option ("get info" > "Options").  Use the "previous" or "next" button in the options window once you start, so you don't have to keep accessing each song.

Just click next and get the next one done, so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing your playcounts and ratings, you can recreate your iTunes library from scratch.

1. Quit iTunes.
2. Drag the "iTunes Music Library.xml" file to the desktop. If you are using iTunes on Windows, delete the file "iTunes Library.itl".  Both of these can be found in your iTunes folder.
3. Start iTunes.
4. Drag the folder "iTunes Music", also in your iTunes folder, into the iTunes window.

Comment: I do mind loosing my playcounts :/